# How is the flow of control in this program involving fork() system call?

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

From what I read about `fork()` system call

Fork system call use for creates a new process, which is called child process, which runs concurrently with parent process

After a new child process created, both processes will execute the next instruction following the fork() system call

`fork()` returns 0 to the child process

`fork()` returns Process ID of newly created child process to parent process (Positive value)

`fork()` returns negative value if child process creation fails

In this piece of code

```
void foo() { 
if (fork() == 0) 
    printf("Hello from Child!\n"); 
else 
    printf("Hello from Parent!\n"); 
} 

int main() { 
    foo(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The output is

```
Hello from Parent!
Hello from Child!
```

The child process was created when the control was inside the condition of `if-else` of function foo in main process.

So from where (which instruction) did the child process start executing?

<s>As it can be observed from the output, `Hello from Parent` is printed when `fork()` returns `0`. So from my understanding `Hello from Parent` was actually printed by the Child Process</s>

`fork()` returned a positive value to the parent process and the parent process printed `Hello from Child`. Is my understanding about this correct?

And from which instruction exactly did the child process started executing? The function call to `fork()` was given inside the condition section of a `if-else`. So the child should have started executing after that `if-else` but that is not what is happening?

Comment: The child process starts immediately after the call of `fork()`. In your example the child process also runs the if-else statement. `Hello from Child!` is printed by the child process, because the return value of `fork()` is 0 for a child process. `Hello from Parent!` is printed by the parent process, because `fork()` returns the PID id of the child process (or -1 if there was an error).

Comment: You can think of fork as a call that returns twice, once in the parent process and once in the new child process which is a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by identifying a primary misconception here:

> As it can be observed from the output, Hello from Parent is printed when fork() returns 0. So from my understanding Hello from Parent was actually printed by the Child Process

The child and the parent are two separate processes running concurrently. The order of these two outputs isn't well-defined, will vary based on your kernel and other timing considerations, and isn't correlated with the fact that your code contains the if/else block written as you have it.<sup>1</sup>

Let's rewrite your code as a linear stream of "instructions" in an abstract sense:

```
0: Function foo():
1:  Invoke system call fork(), no arguments, store result to $1
2:  If $1 is non-zero, jump to label #1.
3:  Invoke C function printf(), argument "Hello from Child!"
4:  Jump to label #2.
5: Label #1:
6:  Invoke C function printf(), argument "Hello from Parent!"
7: Label #2:
8: return control to calling function.
```

Once your program reaches `1:`, the system call is invoked, transferring control to the kernel. The kernel duplicates the process, puts the PID of the child into the return value of `fork` in the parent process, and puts `0` into the return value of `fork` in the child. On x86, the return value is stored in register `eax` (`rax` for x64) as part of the syscall calling convention.

One of these two processes will eventually get scheduled to run by the kernel. In your case, the child process happened to be the first to get scheduled. Your user-mode code took control back from kernel mode, read the return value (out of eax/rax if on x86) which was zero, and did not jump to label #1. It printed `Hello from Child!`, and then returned from the function (to the caller of `foo`, since the child got a copy of the parent's stack).

The same happened for the parent, except the parent got a non-zero value back from the system call, and printed `Hello from Parent!`. It got scheduled to run, and your user-mode code took control from the kernel at the same point, just with a different value returned by the system call.

<sup>1</sup> It's also possible that the two outputs might become interleaved in some way, but that's not as relevant to this discussion, and requires understanding how Linux processes perform I/O.

Comment: It is not only the order of output that isn't well-defined.  It is also quite possible that the output, since both processes write to standard output, is interleaved.  For example  `Hello Hello from Child\n from Parent\n`  where I'm using `\n` to indicate the start of a new line of text on (say) the output window.

Comment: @Peter That's also true, and I'll add a remark about it. My initial concern was that trying to include details of I/O was going to overcomplicate the answer and distract from the more directly relevant concepts of how fork operates and how processes take control back from the system calls when they get scheduled to run.

Answer (score 1):

The child process is a second process that executes in parallel. You might just as easily have gotten

```
Hello from Child!
Hello from Parent!
```

For example, if you have a terminal window open, and you start `firefox &`, which runs “first,” the terminal window or the browser window?  Both are running at the same time.

In fact, Linux starts the child process slightly before it resrarts the parent.  This is because a large number of programs that call `fork()` immediately have the child `exec()` a program, which frees the parent from needing to share all its memory with the child. This is more efficient, because shared memory is copy-on-write.